# This patent is very similar to a Tunisian patent TN2010/0509 deposed the 04/11/2010 in Tunisia

Tags: prior-art, international, wipo

In reference to the patent: [WO 2013/160573 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2013160573A1)

Why has the examiner has not indicated the Tunisian patent TN2010/0509 as a reference like the others?

Comment: From what I can tell, the Tunisian patent search is at the [Institut National de la Normalisation et de la Propriété Industrielle](http://www.innorpi.tn/Eng/brevet_78_265) (INNORPI) but the search is only available in French. Could you post a link to the Tunisian patent?

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://www.epo.org/news-issues/news/2014/20140704.html) from the European Patent Office indicates that Tunisia is not an EPO member state, and only in July 2014 was there an agreement formed (not ratified) between Tunisia and EPO:

> Under the terms of the agreement, signed in Munich on 3 July [2014], European
>   patent applicants and proprietors will be able to validate the legal
>   effects of their European patents and applications on Tunisian
>   territory, even though Tunisia is not an EPO member state. Validated
>   European patent applications and patents will have the same legal
>   effect as Tunisian national applications and patents, and will be
>   subject only to Tunisian patent legislation. The agreement has to be
>   ratified before it can enter into force.

The article goes on to mention that the group has been working on this agreement since 2004.
The WIPO application you mention has a priority date from 2012, and pre-dates the agreement.

I'm certain there are some more specific answers to this question, it depends on how deeply you want to dig into the [WIPO patent legislation](http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/profile.jsp?code=TN).